# Microsoft Teams Bot: replyToId seems to be ignored

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, botframework

i am using the microsoft bot sdk in combination with an restify server (In `package.json`:  `"botbuilder": "^4.11.0"`). I start a waterfall dialog that triggers a long running API. I save the the conversation reference and the id of the sent message to create an reply after the API call is completed:

`replyToId = (await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [ac]})).id;` (in Dialog)

`this.conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);` (in `bot.ts`)

After the completion of the API call, I want to create a reply to the last message of the dialog:

```js
await this.adapter.continueConversation(this.conversationReference, async turnContext => {
    await turnContext.sendActivity(newMessage);
});
```

`newMessage` is the `Activity`-object that contains further information for the user about the result of the API call.
The problem is that `newMessage` is not displayed as an reply to the existing message but as a separate message, although `newMessage.replyToId` is set to `this.replyToId`:

[image: See screenshot]

Additional information: Both messages, the last of the dialog and the "reply" are adaptive cards, but it does not make a difference if I send just simple text, same behaviour.

Would be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "replyToId", put the id of the message you want to reply to, at the end of the conversation reference. As an example, if your conversationReference has a conversationId of `19:ac....cf@thread.skype`, change it to: `19:ac...cf@thread.skype;messageid=12345678`, where `12345678` is what you are currently using for "replyToId"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If I set `this.conversationReference.conversation!.id += ";messageid=" + this.replyToId`, I get the error "unhandled error: Error: Failed to decrypt conversation id". This may be, because conversation.id does not end with `@thread.skype` but is an cryptic string with upper and lower case characters and numbers, something like `a:1uqA...Uf-K...5Ie`. Any other idea?

Comment: Is this a group chat, channel, or 1-1?

Comment: I'm looking more closely at your screenshot, and it looks like 1-1... I think that's the problem... basically, there *is* no concept of "reply" (i.e. "threading") in a 1-1 conversation. Is it 1-1?

Comment: Yes, it it 1-1. There is a feature (currently only on Android?) that you can reply to a message in 1-1 (long tap and hold on message), see [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/2Ou3obh)

Comment: ah ok, then I'm pretty sure that's the issue - you won't be able to "thread" the conversation. It's possible to do a "reply", like you've said (it's possible on desktop/web, but much easier on Android), but it's a "quote + reply" rather than a "continue the thread"

Comment: ok, good to know. is there any way to create such a "quote + reply" with the bot framework? Because that would be enough for me
Just a question out of interest: How do I create an reply on desktop/web?

Comment: On the desktop, basically you start the line with "> " and then type your message. It's essentially just *formatting* as a reply - it's not a *proper* reply in that you can't click it to go back to the previous message, for instance. It also needs you to copy-paste the original message. It's about as unintuitive as you can get ;-)

Comment: As a result of that though, although I don't know of a way to do it with the bot framework, I suspect it's possible using markdown as it's just a marking up of the text as a "quote". You can do it using the full, expanded textbox in Teams client as well, and selecting the "quote" button on the menu.

Comment: Thank you for you help! Indeed, it is possible by using `await context.sendActivity("> quote\n\nreply");"`. If someone has the same problem: You MUST NOT set the `textFormat` entity of the activity, if you do so, a error is thrown :D